# NSTimer memory management in iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, nstimer, instruments

I have an `NSTimer` strong property in a view controler. I create and launch this timer by calling this method:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
   if (self.timer != nil) {
       [self.timer invalidate];
   }

   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(timerDidFinish:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:NO];
}
```

Then, when `timerDidFinish:` is called, I call this method to stop the timer:

```
- (void)stopTimer
{
   if (self.timer != nil) {
       [self.timer invalidate];
       self.timer = nil;
   }
}
```

And after that, I perform some operations. At those operations end I call again `startTimer`. I need to do this to keep regularly performing the operations I need, and to always have the same time (10 secs) between operations.

In `Instruments`, using the `Leaks` template and navigating to the view controller that has this timer, I find that running in an iOS 7 device the `Live Bytes`value and the Allocations graph keep more or less constant along time:

[image: iOS 7 screenshot]

But running in an iOS 6 device this same scenario, `Live Bytes` and Allocations graph steadily increase:

[image: iOS 6 screenshot]

How can I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a repeating timer? And use instruments to see what the allocated objects are.

Comment: Strikes me that you need to go down another level of detail in your analysis. Instruments can tell you what's being allocated and not being released (e.g. option-drag in the allocations graph to select time range and then look into the "allocations summary" and drill into that). Take a look at that and let us know what you find.

Comment: I don't think the timer, itself, is the source of the problem. It could be something as innocuous as some internal cacheing. Hard to say until you identify what's getting allocated and not getting released. Try simulating memory warning and see if you find the memory being recovered or not. Also, how much memory are we talking about? What is the total live bytes in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the heap shot analysis method to have further information about this possible leak. 
The method is pretty straightforward :

Start a debug session with instruments, and go to your viewController with the `NSTimer` property. Wait a little (more than 10 sec to have your timer finish at least once for example, or you can wait for more iterations if you know when the timer ends), then pop back to the previous view controller. In instruments, press "Mark Generation". 
You now have a instant representation of the memory at this time. Go back to your view controller, wait, pop it, create another generation, and repeat a few times.

You should end with a view like this one :

[image: ios Instruments heap generation]

Each generation is represented by a red flag.
The growth column represents memory allocation between two generation. If you don't leak, the Growth should be equals to 0 bytes within a few cycles. If not, you can see the detail of the growth by extending the generation, and see which objects were allocated between the generations. It should help you locating your issue.

For further information about Instruments, you should read this great tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode